# Issues switching from Gulp to Webpack

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, gulp, laravel-mix

I have an old Laravel 5.2 project and am trying to convert it to Laravel 8. I was able to fix the Composer part, but now I am stuck converting the gulpfile.js to webpack.mix.js. Can anyone help?

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var paths = {
    'default': './resources/assets/',
    'jquery': './vendor/bower/jquery/',
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bower/bootstrap-sass/assets/',
    'bootstrapFile': './vendor/bower/bootstrap-fileinput/',
    'bootstrapSwitch': './vendor/bower/bootstrap-switch/dist/',
    'admin': './vendor/bower/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-sass/',
    'social': './vendor/bower/bootstrap-social/',
    'fonts': './vendor/bower/font-awesome/',
    'tables': './vendor/bower/datatables/media/',
    'tablesPlugins': './vendor/bower/datatables-plugins/',
    'tablesResponsive': './vendor/bower/datatables-responsive/',
    'metisMenu': './vendor/bower/metisMenu/',
    'raphael': './vendor/bower/raphael/',
    'morris': './vendor/bower/morrisjs/',
    'redactor': './vendor/bower/redactor/',
    'select2': './vendor/bower/select2/dist/',
    'sortable': './vendor/bower/jquery-sortable/source/',
    'validation': './vendor/bower/jquery-validation/dist/',
    'waypoints': './vendor/bower/waypoints/lib/',
    'scrollTo': './vendor/bower/jquery.scrollTo/',
    'usMap': './vendor/bower/us-map/',
    'tipso': './vendor/bower/tipso/src/',
    'owlCarousel': './vendor/bower/owl.carousel/dist/'
};

elixir(function (mix) {
    /* Admin */
    mix.sass("admin/app.scss", 'public/assets/admin/css/', {
        includePaths: [
            paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/',
            paths.bootstrapFile + 'css/',
            paths.admin + 'sass/',
            paths.fonts + 'scss/',
            paths.tables + 'css/',
            paths.tablesResponsive + 'css/',
            paths.metisMenu + 'dist/',
            paths.morris,
            paths.social,
            paths.redactor + 'redactor/',
            paths.select2 + 'css/'
        ]
    })
        .copy(paths.fonts + 'fonts', 'public/assets/admin/fonts')
        .copy(paths.bootstrap + 'fonts/bootstrap', 'public/assets/admin/fonts/bootstrap')
        .copy(paths.tables + 'images', 'public/assets/admin/images')
        .copy(paths.bootstrapFile + 'img', 'public/assets/admin/images')
        .scripts([
                paths.jquery + 'jquery.js',
                paths.bootstrap + 'javascripts/bootstrap.js',
                paths.bootstrapFile + 'js/fileinput.min.js',
                paths.bootstrapSwitch + 'js/bootstrap-switch.min.js',
                paths.tables + 'js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                paths.tablesResponsive + 'js/dataTables.responsive.js',
                paths.metisMenu + 'dist/metisMenu.js',
                paths.raphael + 'raphael.js',
                paths.morris + 'morris.js',
                paths.admin + 'dist/js/sb-admin-2.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/counter.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/definedlinks.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/editormode.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/filemanager.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/fontcolor.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/fontfamily.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/fontsize.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/imagemanager.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/limiter.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/table.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/textdirection.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/textexpander.js',
                paths.redactor + 'redactor/redactor-plugins/video.js',
                paths.select2 + 'js/select2.js',
                paths.sortable + 'js/jquery-sortable.js',
                paths.default + 'js/admin/file-input.module.js',
                paths.default + 'js/admin/postal-target.module.js',
                paths.default + 'js/admin/spend.module.js',
                paths.default + 'js/admin/custom.js'
            ],
            'public/assets/admin/js/admin.js',
            './'
        );

    /* Front */
    mix.sass('front/app.scss', 'public/assets/css/', {
        includePaths: [
            paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/'
        ]
    })
        .scripts([
                paths.jquery + 'jquery.js',
                paths.validation + "jquery.validate.min.js",
                paths.waypoints + "jquery.waypoints.min.js",
                paths.scrollTo + "jquery.scrollTo.min.js",
                paths.tipso + "tipso.js",
                paths.owlCarousel + "owl.carousel.js",
                paths.default + 'js/front/validation.module.js',
                paths.default + "js/front/job-filter.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/distance-picker.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/apply-validation.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/contact-validation.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/profile-tabs.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/state-hover.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/main.js"

            ],
            'public/assets/js/app.js',
            './'
        )
        .scripts([
                paths.default + "js/front/vendor/raphael.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/vendor/jquery.usmap.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/map.js"
            ],
            'public/assets/js/map.js',
            './'
        );
        //.version([ 'assets/css/app.css', 'assets/js/app.js' ]);

    // iFrame
    mix.sass([
            'iframe/truckingTruth.scss'
        ],
        'public/assets/css/truckingTruth.css')
        .scripts([
                paths.jquery + 'jquery.js',
                paths.validation + "jquery.validate.min.js",
                paths.default + "js/front/apply-validation.js"
            ],
            'public/assets/js/truckingTruth.js',
            './'
        );
    
    //.version([ 'assets/css/truckingTruth.css' ]);

    mix.version(['assets/css/app.css', 'assets/js/app.js', 'assets/css/truckingTruth.css', 'assets/js/truckingTruth.js'])
});
```